# How to create edesk private key using javascript libs

Tags: key, private

I'm using [sotez](https://github.com/AndrewKishino/sotez), but I don't know how to convert `edsk` to `edesk` like tezos-client.

```
var mnemonic = crypto.generateMnemonic();
crypto.generateKeys(mnemonic, pass).then(function (data) { /* data.sk prefix is edsk, not edesk */ }
```

Any solutions?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. I think that the prefix of tezos-client private keys are also `edsk`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I remember that it was edsk before. Now I need a password when I do `gen key`.

Comment: Ah, I see. `edesk` keys are encrypted, password-protected, `edsk` keys. With tezos-client, edsk is generated by `gen keys`. To generate edsk, do `gen keys --encrypted`. Unfortunately, I don't know how to do this with sotez. Try posting an issue on their github page: https://github.com/AndrewKishino/sotez/issues

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with sotez@8.0.0. There is a new method `cryptoUtils.encryptSecretKey(secretKey, password)` which encrypts secret keys into the 'esk' format.
https://github.com/AndrewKishino/sotez/wiki/Documentation#encryptsecretkey