# How to get encrypted Tezos private key from decrypted private key and password?

Tags: taquito, javascript, secret-key, encrypt

In my app on back-end the next code is used to get signer:

```
const { InMemorySigner } = require('@taquito/signer');

const signer = InMemorySigner.fromSecretKey(
  signingKey,
  TEZOS_SERVICE_PASSPHRASE
)
```

where TEZOS_SERVICE_PASSPHRASE - some passphrase, that need to be used on front-end to encrypt secret key.
According to Taquito documentation https://tezostaquito.io/typedoc/classes/_taquito_signer.inmemorysigner.html, second param is a *Passphrase to decrypt the private key if it is encrypted*.
But how can I encrypt secret key using passphrase on front-end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not required to have an encrypted key `edesk`, you can just provide the `edsk` without password and encrypt your wallet storage the way you prefer.

Answering your exact question:

- **Python solution:** https://tezos.stackexchange.com/a/4212/318
- **Javascript solution:** https://tezos.stackexchange.com/a/3172/318